# How to gives error responce if email is registered in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.7

I am making laravel api for registration with validation ,the proble is how to return responce if user is registered with responce below are my code please help me...

```
 public function register(Request $request)
    {

       $this->Validation($request);

       $users = User::create($request->all());

    if($users==='email'){
          return response(["error" => "Your error here"], 400);
       }
        return $users;

    }

    public function Validation($request)
    {
        return $this->validate($request,[
             'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
             'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
             'username' => 'required|max:255',
             'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
             'mobile' => 'required|max:255',
             'password' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: The default controller's validation method should already return a response if the email is taken. You don't need to do any additional checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#manually-creating-validators) official document to validate request.

But i will suggest the second way to validate request which is more effective.

Using Custom Request

1. Check the steps https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests
2. Create Custom Request
3. Add Rules
4. Use Custom Request in Controller

Check the example in a boilerplate i have published on [Gitlab](https://github.com/brnrajoriya/laravel-5-6-ip-address-auth-xml-uploader-postgres)

1. [The Custom Request](https://github.com/brnrajoriya/laravel-5-6-ip-address-auth-xml-uploader-postgres/blob/master/app/Http/Requests/IpAddressRequest.php)
2. [The Controller](https://github.com/brnrajoriya/laravel-5-6-ip-address-auth-xml-uploader-postgres/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/AdminController.php)

Comment: please code for me...thanks in advance@Bhaskar Rajoriya

Comment: I have updated the Answer with example reference. Please check.
Thanks

Comment: If you are creating only APIs in laravel. Then start the project using this boilerplate. https://github.com/francescomalatesta/laravel-api-boilerplate-jwt

Comment: how to return in api if email is registerd in this code               public function register(Request $request)
    {

       $this->Validation($request);
       
       $users = User::create($request->all());

        return $users;
        
    } @Bhaskar Rajoriya

Comment: The Registration Function should be like https://github.com/francescomalatesta/laravel-api-boilerplate-jwt/blob/master/app/Api/V1/Controllers/SignUpController.php

Comment: i am not using jwt